Where to find this "double" 90 degree terminal block
I'm after this little metal parts to connect a terminal block to a pcb that is to be fitted inside the box shown in the picture. My problem looking for this revolved around the fact that 'right angle' or '90 degrees' terminal block are mostly a rotation alongside the 'other' axis. The board would be in the same plane/direction as the card seen in this picture. Anyone familiar with this kind of wire/connection could could maybe help me out?


I'm looking but I suggest changing the question to something like "what is the name for..." since specific supplier recommendations are off topic here.

Usually the company that makes the housing will also offer terminal blocks to fit.

I'm seeing a few, but as Spehro mentioned they're listed as accessories to or components of enclosures which does make some sense since the dimensions would have to be very specific to line up with the holes on the enclosure and the "flipped" orientation makes them pretty flimsy and therefore unsuitable for applications where you don't absolutely need it. Some examples from Phoenix Contact and TE, respectively:


